# Shell Compiler to Program

Tags: gui, shell-scripting

> I am looking for a simple program, preferably with GUI capabilities, to create small, usable programs.

I would like to compile my multiple scripts (Backup, Cron Job, Task Kills etc.) I have currently sitting as .sh files being executed into a program. I would like to set a basic GUI to perform the tasks of interacting with the end user. I know there was a method in the terminal to have a menu pop out for users to select an item, and then the approrpriate action occur, I do not want this.

### A little background on the task at hand.

I need to (for a course), setup a small network of computer's to run a standardized platform. This however cannot be automatized, I need to deliver each PC (as the hardware varies), it's own OS (in this instance, Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS x64) yet have each PC mimic the other. I plan on achieving this with a small program the "user" can run upon install, and it should perform the following:

1. Install a specific set of programs onto the user's PC, and also set a few variables.
2. Create the same paths for file storage (/home/NAME/PathI/) and also map network drives
3. Create a backup scheme and also a localised server to retain old user profiles (as in, I need to backup /home/user/*)to a server

So the point is made. I want to make a simple-to-use program with basic buttons that can run a **silent** script in the background. I know on Window's I used Advanced Bat To EXE to create batch scripts to run invisible when a user selected a button- what is the alternative to this in Ubuntu?

It is also important to note that I am not good with **any scripting language**, so I cannot create an actual program myself. I know, sort of makes this difficult right?

I have done a bit of looking at found the following:

1. [Zenity](http://www.linux.org/threads/zenity-gui-for-shell-scripts.5567/)
2. [WhipTail](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was quite odd; I performed everything in Nano and exported the results.

This was not easy to perform, but it was good to be able to paste the command into another terminal, execute and then come back to.